# How to solve for roots in a non-linear equation? Do I use SciPy?

Tags: python, scipy

[Link to Complicated Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCzQ0.png)

I'm trying to find Ts for a given time. I have all necessary variables in the above equation, except for Ts. I realized that I can integrate with respect to t, which makes things a little easier. From there, how do I go about solving for Ts?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a root-finding problem. This is a differential equation, which you can solve using e.g. `solve_ivp` from scipy.integrate. You will need the initial value for T(t=0).